# Export QGIS map for Google Map

Tags: qgis, google-maps, export

I made a map with QGIS that I really would like to export in Google map format (Zoom/X/Y.png).

I search everywhere and no comfortable answer was found.

For now, I am making a map using TillMill, export it in MBTiles and then use mb-util (https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to convert it to Z/X/Y format.
This is painful, and the QGIs map style interface is much better than the hand coded Carto CSS for TileMill

Comment: are you just wanting a vector kml/kmz? or do you want an image overlay to use in google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QTiles` plugin should deliver what you want. You have to allow for experimental plugins to get it.

If you want the tiles inside Openlayers or leaflet in the usual World Mercator projection, set EPSG:3857 as **project** CRS before starting the plugin.

Comment: Yes! It does the trick!
By the way, QGIS is much better than TileMill. 
It is faster and color edition is easier.

You save my week! Thanks again